# Include multiple templates with their CSS and JavaScript codes

Tags: jinja2

How can I include the following template (there are many of such template) in the main template so that each block gets appended to the corresponding block in the main template? Actually I want to avoid adding CSS and JavaScript separately each time I include a template, so asking this question.

```
{% block head %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/navbar.css">
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div id="navbar"></div>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script src="/static/navbar.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Main template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% block head %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main.css">
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"></div>

        {% block body %} {% endblock %}

        <div id="footer"></div>

        {% block script %}
            <script src="/static/main.js"></script>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are looking for the `extend` functionality as described in [Child Template](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#child-template)

Comment: But I need to extend many parents which is not possible in jinja2 AFAIK.

Comment: What do you mean by _"extend many parents"_?

Comment: Parent templates. When the main template gets loaded, I want the individual templates inside it be loaded too with their CSS putted in the head section.

Comment: You are seeing the parent / child in the wrong way. Parent template is what you have in _"Main template"_, all the rest are children, so all your children just have to rewrite the `head` block, and voilà. And yes if this is the question, AFAIK, you can have an extended template extend another template (like a chain of extend).

Comment: OK, but in my Flask code I always want to return the main template to render. But now I have to return the children.